# Text wont save to DB when using WYSWIG

Tags: php, mysql, database, wysiwyg

I have a form which saves to a DB. When i use a normal textarea the text saves in the DB, however when using nicedit WYSIWYG editor the text doesnt save.

Here is my code

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>

<form class='form-inline' role='form' action='update_news.php?q=$id' method='post'> 
 <textarea name='news' cols='10' rows='3' class='form-control'>$news</textarea>
<button class='btn btn-success btn-small' type='submit'><i class='icon-ok'></i> Update </button></a>
```

Update News:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM news where id='1' ")or die('You need select a audit trail' );
$f1=$_POST[title];  
$f2=$_POST[news];
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET title='$f1', news='$f2' WHERE id='1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

If i remove the `<script>` and have a basic `textarea` the db updates, but doesn't with the script.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the error ? Can we see `update_news.php` ?

Comment: As far as I know `nicEdit` does not sync the editor content with the `textarea` and you need to do this by hand calling `saveContent` for each instance. You should also keep in mind that `nicEdit` no longer under active development and that you probably should choose a library that is still maintained.

Comment: @André - I have updated the question to include this.

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NicEdit doesn't automatically save its contents into the textarea on submit, even though it's supposed to do it according to their [documentation](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API)...

> This method syncs the content of the editor with the textarea value - this is done automatically if the form with the orginal  is submitted.

However we can do that manually :

```
<textarea id="news" name='news' cols='10' rows='3' class='form-control'>$news</textarea>

<button class='btn btn-success btn-small' type='submit' onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('news').saveContent();><i class='icon-ok'></i> Update </button>
```

The textarea now has an ID "news" which allows us to find it later.

The button now has a onclick function which finds the NicEditor at the "news" textarea and saves its contents to the textarea.